How can I change the VC++ Directories default $(LibraryPath)?
Somehow, the default Library Directory got changed to a seemingly random folder.

As shown in the screenshot, the inherited $(LibraryPath) property is a program files directory that has nothing to do with Visual Studio or development in general.
I checked the %LIB% environment variable in the developer console, and everything therte looks correct.
PS C:\Users\mbuca\source\repos> echo $env:LIB
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x86

So how do I change the VC++ Library directories back to the correct defaults?

Do I understand correctly that this wrong path appears as default for every new project you create in Visual Studio? Then perhaps some built-in default property sheet file (*.props) got corrupted. Look into Microsoft.Cpp.VCTools.Content.props and Microsoft.Cpp.VCTools.props (you can use Notepad++ and select XML from its Language menu, to view the files conveniently). Those files are located probably in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170". Anyway, search if that "Cabinet Pro" string occurs there.

@heapunderrun Yes, your understanding is correct. New instance of VS 2022, new solution, new DLL template project. I found the folder and used notepad++ to search every file in the VC directory (I have three versions in that folder) for "Cabinet", and there were 0 hits.
